# How to make a for loop

Tags: matlab

I have a big code but i want to make a for loop to execute the code.My code is below:

```
A = zeros(1, 60) ;
C = A ;
D = A ;
F = A ;
.......


  if( sum(B) == 100 )
    A= A(1) + 1;

  elseif( sum(B) == (99) )
        C(1) = C(1) + 1;
  elseif( sum(B) == (98) )
        D(1) = D(1) + 1;
  elseif( sum(B) == (97) )
        E(1) = E(1) + 1;    
.........
end
O1=A;
O2=C;
O3=D;
O4=F;
O=[O1,O2,O3,O4]
```

I need to check upto `sum(B)==1`
so its looks worse if i write the whole condition using `elseif` so i want to use a `for loop` to execute this condition.But i cant do this.

Matlab experts needs your valuable sugggestion and help.

Comment: Check [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/31156-for-loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
A = zeros(100,60);

for k=100:-1:1
    if sum(B) == k
       A(101-k,1) = A(101-k,1) + 1;
    end
end
```

Note that it's never a good idea to do equality tests on floating point numbers though, better to compare the difference to a small tolerance value.

Comment: You don't really need a `for` loop. You can do something like: `k = sum(B); if (k>=1 & k<=100), A(101-k,1) = A(101-k,1) + 1;, end`

Answer (score 2):

If would be better to replace `A, B, C...` by a cell array: `X{1}, X{2}, X{3},...`:

```
X = cell(1,100); % change "100" as needed
[X{:}] = deal(zeros(1,60)); % initialize each cell as needed
X{101-sum(B)}(1) = X{101-sum(B)}(1) + 1; % or whatever operation is required here
```

If all your former `A, B, C, ...` have the same size, you can use an array instead of a cell array.

Comment: Nice. Same idea as my answer, without a for loop.

Comment: I just wrote in your answer about not needing a loop :-)